# Can I convert a Map<String, List<Integer>> into a MultiValueMap<String, Integer>

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to convert a map into multivalue map, but I am getting the below compilation exception:

`Wrong 1st argument type. Found: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>, required: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> less...  Inspection info:`

Here is the structure:
`Map<String, List<String>> tradersTradeMap` - >  `MultiValueMap<String, String>tradersTradeMap`

```
class Trade {

  public String getTraderNameAfterProcesing (MultiValueMap<String, String> 
      tradersTradeMap){
      ..... // SOme code goes here
   }

}

class Customer {

private Trade trade;

public String Method1(){
   Map<String, List<String>> traderTradeMap = new HashMap<>();
   traderTradeMap.put("TraderA", Arrays.asList("SPOT","BLOCK","FORWARD"));
   traderTradeMap.put("TraderB", Arrays.asList("SPOT","BLOCK"));

   trade = new Trade();
   trade.getTraderNameAfterProcesing(traderTradeMap); // This line is giving exception 

}

}
```

Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: How are you trying to convert it?

Comment: It was throwing while calling the method. I have edited my question with code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't care about which `MultiValueMap` type you use, the easiest way to do it is to use `LinkedMultiValueMap`'s [copy constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html#LinkedMultiValueMap-java.util.Map-) which takes a `Map<K, List<V>>`

One problem in your example is that you're trying to give the original map and the `MultiValueMap` the same variable name. So, if you instead did something like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> TradersTradeMVMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(TradersTradeMap);
```

Comment: In my example, looks like I've to convert into a multivaluemap first and then pass as an argument. This above example should work. Let me try. But I thought this auto conversion will take place.

Comment: You can pass a `MultiMap` anywhere that Java expects to see a `Map`, but **not** the other way around.  This is because `MultiMap` has `Map` as a parent and you can always treat an object or interface as if it were its parent or anything higher in the inheritance chain.  To put it a different way: all cats are animals, but not all animals are cats.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Spring provides a handy wrapper in the form of `CollectionUtils.toMultiValueMap()`, which preserves the original `Map` used.